# Error while importing a csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I tried importing a csv file using

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("samle.csv")
```

But there is an error while importing the file :

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 28: invalid start byte
```

As i looked in the csv file, it had some characters like this:
     �
How do i rectify this error?

Comment: this may seem stupid for a comment... but could you just remove the special character? or are there multiple characters like this?

Comment: Too many of them...About 5k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
df = pd.read_csv("samle.csv", encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

Comment: @user517696, try `ISO-8859-1` instead of `utf-8` as that character is often associated with ISO.

Comment: @zipa Can you update your answer based on my comment? Thanks!